# Задача на использование коллекции Map

Tags: javascript, коллекции

Даны инпуты. В каждый инпут можно ввести число. Пусть по нажатию на Enter инпут запоминает введенное число. Сделайте так, чтобы по потери фокуса в инпуте в консоль выводился массив всех введенных ранее в инпут чисел.
Задачу надо решить с использованием коллекции Map
Вот мой код:

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
let map = new Map;
for(let input of inputs){   
    let map = new Map;
    let i=1
        input.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){   
            if(event.code === 'Enter' || event.code === 'NumpadEnter' ){    

            map.set(i++,this.value);            
            this.value = '';
            
            input.addEventListener('blur',()=>{
                console.log([...map.values()])
            })  
            }                   
    })      
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1425924/178988 - тут есть вариант с map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы в качестве ключа в `Map` был индекс, то его лучше вынести за пределы цикла иначе у вас в `Map` будет столько же элементов, сколько и инпутов. Так же у вас в обработчике события `keydown` постоянно создаются новые слушатели события `blur`, его тоже нужно вынести отдельно.

Если я правильно понял, то должно работать как-то так:

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
let map = new Map();

let index = 0;
for(let input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {   
     if (event.code !== 'Enter' && event.code !== 'NumpadEnter' ) return; 
     map.set(index, this.value);
     index++;
     this.value = '';                    
  });
  input.addEventListener('blur', ()=> {
    console.log([...map.values()])
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value=""></input>
<input type="number" value=""></input>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, да все работает так как и должно! Не могли бы вы еще пояснить, для чего здесь return после if?

Comment: @Виктория Чтобы не создавать вложенность, возвращается `void`, если были нажаты любые кнопки на клавиатуре, кроме `Enter` и `NumpadEnter`.  Так называемый "Return early pattern"(Ранний возврат).

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение!

Comment: @Виктория Мне кажется или каждый инпут должен сохранять только свои значения? Или все инпуты свои значения должны хранить в одном месте?